# Question on Index Sets: $[-n, \frac{1}{n})$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I'm currently working on an index set problem over the interval $[-n, \frac{1}{n})$, and would like to check my answers.

For the union from $n=1$ to infinity, I'm getting $[-n,1]$ (figuring that every value possible must live inside of that interval).

For the intersection from $n=1$ to infinity, I'm the figuring the answer is the empty set, because I cannot find a value that is present in each set.

Am I close?

Edit: $n$ is an element of $\mathbb Z$, I should add.

Comment: How can the answer for the union depend on the value of $n$? Also, as hint for the last one, check $-0.5$ ;)

Comment: Isn't the union the set of all values present over the interval? You can't get a value larger than 1 in this case, right? Also, for the second part, aren't negative values not apart of the set in this case (we are going from 1 to infinity)?

Comment: I want a clarification: Are you interested in $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty [-n,1/n)$ and $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty [-n,1/n)$? If you respond to this comment, then it will likely increase the chances of someone providing an explanation of some of the mistakes you have.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly it.

Comment: Wait, so is $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}$, or in $\mathbb{N}$?

Answer (score 0):

For the union:

$$\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} [-n,1/n) = \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} ([-n,0] \cup [0,1/n)) = (\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}[-n,0]) \cup (\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}[0,1/n)) = (-\infty,0] \cup [0,1) = (-\infty,1)$$

Now the intersection $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} [-n,1/n) = [-1,0]$. Consider $x \in \mathbb{R}$:

$$x > 0 \Rightarrow \exists n \in \mathbb{N}^+ \text{ such that } x \not\in [0,1/n) \Rightarrow x \not\in \cap_{n=1}^{\infty} [-n,1/n)$$

$$0 \geq x \geq -1 \Rightarrow x \in [-n,0] \text{ for } n = 1, \ldots, \infty \Rightarrow x \in \cap_{n=1}^{\infty} [-n,1/n)$$

$$-1 > x \Rightarrow x \not\in [-1,0] \Rightarrow x \not\in \cap_{n=1}^{\infty} [-n,1/n)$$